# How do I pull my colleague's work (repository) from git hub to VScode using Python?

Tags: git, repository, commit, git-push, git-pull

Git beginner here. Please help me to get my colleague's repository form GitHub to my VScode. In his absence I need to run API tests. Thank you for your help.

Comment: The "using python" part of the title seems weird. It's like asking how you get from point A to point B "using a spoon": the spoon isn't helpful, at all, here. You get from point A to point B by walking, driving, taking the bus or train, etc. You can bring a spoon (or Python) with you if you want, but nobody will care.

Comment: There are multiple questions here in one. For "pulling my colleague's work (repository) from git hub to VScode", you can start with the VS Code docs on using Git: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol#_cloning-a-repository. For "using Python" and "run API tests" part... that seems to be separate question.

Answer (score 1):

To copy a GitHub repository to a local folder you just need to run the `git clone` command, followed by the url of the repository. Once you have done that, you can open it in VScode and it will automatically detect it as a git folder.

For more info on the topic, view the [GitHub docs](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/cloning-a-repository) page on cloning.